# Jquery/AJax Trying to store the form data in a global variable array such as $_POST?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I am trying to submit the form data using jQuery/AJAX and then store the value into a universally accessible array. I am doing all this to prevent a page reload problem on form submission and then store the form data into a browser cookie.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#form").submit(function() {
    $.post("test.php", $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
      //$("#form").after('<div>' + data + '</div>');

    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<?php if (count($_POST)) print_r($_POST); else { ?>
<html>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<form id="form" action="" method="post">
  First Name :
  <input name="fname">Last Name :
  <input name="lname">Address :
  <input name="address">Contact No. :
  <input name="contact">Country:
  <input name="country">City:
  <input name="city">
  <input type="submit" id="btn-ser1" value="Serialize" />
</form>

</html>
<?php } print_r($_POST); ?>
```

Comment: Hi, Parth When you are using post method in jQuery ajax the values already assigned to $_POST variable. So what exactly you want to do?

Comment: Yes you are right.. But as i am printing out the $_POST array... nothing gets printed out

Comment: could you tell me that given html code is from test.php or the page where you are using script.

Comment: Are you talking about `print_r` on the first line or the last line?

Comment: The last line will be executed even if the page wasn't loaded by AJAX, since it's outside the `if`.